# store user language selection in ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am developing a multi language (Arabic and English) app, where user will select language from settings.

I used a `UITableView` to show two cells; for Arabic and English. Here the user can select only one selection. But my problem is where to store the user selection so that I can use the selected language for my whole application depending upon the user selection. As am new to iOS.

Should I create a key in `info.plist`, use a global variable or any other best way?

Thanks

Comment: means want to store what user is selected English or Arabic. that's it ?

Comment: Yes. From other classes i should get the value and change the content accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we discussed In comment You want to store Value what user is selected English or Arabic than for this you can user [NSUserDefalut](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).
here is the example like user selected English.

Set the Object with Key

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
// saving an NSString
[prefs setObject:@"English" forKey:@"SelectedLanguage"];
```

Get the Object with Key

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
// getting an NSString
NSString *languageSeleted = [prefs stringForKey:@"SelectedLanguage"];
```

try this

Comment: hi madan, your solution is working but Is this object value remain permanent, i mean user close the app the selection should not change. if user select english the language should not change until user select other language.

Comment: You need to close the App as i think you app running in background. this is not issue we can achieve this

Answer (score 2):

There is `NSLocalizedString(key, comment)` for that.
There is a nice tutorial here :
http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

In my way, I would like to use a value in plist to save the selection.

Maybe there's other simple way to do it.

Good luck.